# Zero-inflation with binomial data?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

So I have a presence/absence (1/0) dataset and right now I am trying to find out which model to use. My data looks like this:
Dependent var: presence/absence (95% zero's)
Independent var: month (1:12), hour (0-23), location and individual (random in mixed model).

Since the data consists for approx. 95% of zeros, I started to wonder if there is something like 'zero-inflation' in logistic regression?

Answer (score 2):

No. There are only two outcomes in logistic regression, adding a zero-inflated component is pointless. Also, having many zeroes does not imply zero-inflation. Zero-inflation means more zeroes *than expected* under your model. So first fit the model and you'll see that it will manage to deal with the zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

No, however your model will have convergence problems if there is complete separation of the outcome between treatments, i.e. if a month has only 0s or only 1s.